# Is SHA-512 in "certutil" case insensitive?

Tags: hash, case-sensitive, sha512, certutil

I downloaded a file and used `certutil` to verify the integrity of a file I downloaded (command attached below). The uploader provided a SHA-512 hash with all letters capitalized, while `certutil` provided a hash with all letters in lowercase. Is SHA-512 in `certutil` case insensitive?

```
certutil -hashfile "file_location" SHA512
```

Comment: the hash output is a hexadecimal string and hex values aren't case-sensitive, a and A are both the same